# listview on select the item in list display a detail activity

Tags: android

```
private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_list);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            int itemPosition     = position;

            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
           // String add = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address))
             //       .getText().toString();
           // String  description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                   //.getText().toString();

            //String sweet = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.home))
               //     .getText().toString();


            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
           in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
            //in.putExtra(TAG_ADDRESS,add);
            //in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
           // in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_HOME,sweet);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

                 //   String add = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                   String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                  contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                   // contact.put(TAG_ADDRESS,add);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_HOME,home);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                SearchActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                TAG_PHONE_MOBILE ,TAG_PHONE_HOME }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile,R.id.home });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

I have a list activity in the list it display the name,email,phone number on select an item in the list open a new activity and display the same name, email,number but i need others details in nextactivity including addrees,gender,home, office

In the nextactivity i displaying this items

```
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";

private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    String email = in.getStringExtra(TAG_EMAIL);
    String mobile = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
    String home = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_HOME);


    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblMobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
    TextView lblMobiles = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_labels);

    lblName.setText(name);
    lblEmail.setText(email);
    lblMobile.setText(mobile);
    lblMobiles.setText(home);
}
```

}

Inclusignthsi i want to display address,home,office .

Comment: Please rephrase your question, currently it's very hard to understand what's the problem.

Comment: post your other activity.

Comment: @subhas i added my other see that

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
 private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
 private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";

    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);

// getting intent data
Intent in = getIntent();

// Get JSON values from previous intent
String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
String email = in.getStringExtra(TAG_EMAIL);
String mobile = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
String home = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_HOME);


// Displaying all values on the screen
TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
TextView lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
TextView lblMobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
TextView lblMobiles = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_labels);

lblName.setText(name);
lblEmail.setText(email);
lblMobile.setText(mobile);
lblMobiles.setText(home);
}
```

@subhas i have updated th other activity code